# The second order differential equation non-linear case

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-conditions

I'm working to solve this equation but it's not giving me anything

```
a = 1; b = 0.24; k = 0.002; f = 0.68;
  sol = NDSolve[{x''[t]*x[t] + (3 a/2 - 1) (x'[x])^2 - 3 b/2 (x'[t]*x[t]) + k ((3 a - 1)/2) - a*f x[t]^2 == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}];
  Plot[{x[t] /. sol, x'[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: `NDSolve` needs two initial or boundary conditions for this ode

Comment: You can multiply through `eq1` by `x[t]` in your other post by editing the question, if that's what you want.  It doesn't essentially change the problem, so it would be an acceptable edit.

Comment: You also have `x'[x]` in your code. You probably meant `x'[t]`.